# custom code to run on server on every silverlight poll. (polling duplex)

Tags: wcf, silverlight, push, polling, duplex

Is it possible to run custom code when the silverlight client polls everytime to the server to keep the connection alive. My application is a implementation of the comet style polling duplex communication which is available from silverlight3.
I found that it sends the following Soap message on every poll.

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Body>
    <wsmc:MakeConnection xmlns:wsmc="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-rx/wsmc/200702">
        <wsmc:Address>
            http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-rx/wsmc/200702/anoynmous?id=7f64eefe-9328-4168-8175-1d4b82bef9c3
        </wsmc:Address>>
    </wsmc:MakeConnection>
</s:Body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that should be possible, but having not worked with duplex services myself I can't be 100% on this. I've used the following method: [System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.IDispatchMessageInspector.AfterReceiveRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.idispatchmessageinspector.aspx) implemented on the server side to intercept all incoming messages to strip out some security information from the message and run some custom code before it reaches the service layer.

I found this [Paolo Pialorsi Article](http://weblogs.asp.net/paolopia/archive/2007/08/23/writing-a-wcf-message-inspector.aspx) useful when implementing my solution.